# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement donkeypart_picamera

Tags: picamera

I was trying to install donkeypart_picamera but then I'm getting an error

```
pip install donkeypart_picamera
```

I get this error

> *ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement donkeypart_picamera (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for donkeypart_picamera*

Comment: Is it https://pypi.org/project/donkeycar/ that you've spelled wrong?

Comment: which part do you think I've spelled wrong ? Btw Im not using a picamera, using a nother camera that came with the kit car